# javascript form validation

Tags: javascript

I am writing a javascript form validation of PreSaveAction() as below:

```
    function PreSaveAction() {  
    var number1 = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("INPUT","TextField","Quantity");  
    //var ddl1 = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("select","DropDownChoice","Is Product Completed"); 
    var myvar = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("TextArea","TextField","Description");  
    //if (dropdown1.value == "Yes" && date1.value == "")  
    if (number1.value == "" || myvar.value === "") 
    {  
        alert("Please fill all the Required Fields");  
        return false; // Cancel the item save process  
    }  

   if(confirm("Do you want to continue with this information?")==true)
   {

    alert("Successfully Submitted");
   return true; // OK to proceed with the save item 

    }

    return false; 

}
```

and the script for getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle function

```
function getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle(tagName, identifier, title) {  
    var len = identifier.length;  
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);  

    for (var i=0; i < tags.length; i++) {  
        var tempString = tags[i].id;  
        if (tags[i].title == title && (identifier == "" || tempString.indexOf(identifier) == tempString.length - len)) {  
            return tags[i];  
        }  
    }  
    return null;  
}
```

what i have observed above is it is not validating both the fields together where i am using and operator.

Am i doing something wrong in the script

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need to see the code for `getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle` function or at least know what exactly it returns - is it the actual form element? Also what you mean "not validating both fields"? You fill only one and still get to the `confirm`?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Added complete code including getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle function  and you are right i fill one field still get to the confirm?

Answer (score 3):

It is often better to use "===" instead of "==" since that includes type checking as well.

Comment: True, when you reach 50 reputation please post such things as comment on specific question or answer. :)

Comment: @Shadow: true, I've duly helped him on his way. :-)

Comment: there ya go. enjoy commenting.

Answer (score 2):

You have more than one element with the same ID, and this cause only the first element to be returned by your function.

Have unique ID for each element then change the second line to something like:

```
var myvar = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("TextArea", "txtDescription", "Description");
```

Assuming you now have `id="txtDescription"` to the textarea element.

Alternativly you can assign the same **class** to more than one element, but can't see any reason why you can't give different ID.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the test to fail if **either** of the values are empty, you want the OR property: ||

This will make sure they both are non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
var number1 = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("INPUT","TextField","Quantity");  (TextBox)

var Desc1 = getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle("TextArea","TextField","Description");  (MultiLine)


if (number1.value == "" || Desc1.value == "") //Changed here
    {  
        alert("Please fill all the Required Fields");  
        return false; // Cancel the item save process  
    }  
return true;
```

Comment: it is still not validating Multiline Field

Answer (score 0):

```
if (number1.value == "" || Desc1.value == "") 
    {  
        alert("Please fill all the Required Fields");  
        return false; // Cancel the item save process  
    }  
return true;
```

You want to use an or here. cause you want to be both fields set, right?

```
if (number1.value != "" && Desc1.value != "")
```

Is also possible.

To validate the number correctly:

```
number1.length && !isNaN(Number(number1.value)); //Number("") returns 0, not NaN
```

Comment: Yes i want to both fields to be required and i have updated the complete code snippet on the top again.  I think the first time it is validating and the second time it is not checking

Comment: What do you mean by first an second time? Do you really mean you get different results on different runs?
Like Shadow Wizard said: You should show us `getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle`.